# Synonym wanted for 'make it easy '

Tags: grammaticality, synonyms

I am confused about how to write the sentence below. Is it grammatically correct?

> Our mission is to make it easy to post or search institute.

Are there any alternate phrases for "make it easy"?

Comment: Is 'search institute' a multiword verb I've missed? 'Make it easy to' is totally idiomatic and the natural choice in conversation, but mixing it with business jargon is rather incongruous.

Comment: "**simplify** posting or searching"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _Search institute_ makes sense to me (given context—I’m making up my own to fit, of course). It’s _post institute_ that I’m having trouble making any sense of. Last time I checked, institutes generally didn’t fit in post boxes …

Answer (score 2):

[Facilitate:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facilitate) :

> - to make (something) easier : to help cause (something)
> - to help (something) run more smoothly and effectively

Comment: Unless as a sleep aid, IMO this word should not ever be used.

Answer (score 1):

Since, like Edwin Ashworth and (to some extent) Janus Bahs Jacquet, I can't figure out what the intended intended meaning of the phrase "post or search institute" is, I will drop the word institute from my suggested alternatives to "make it easy to."

One option is to use the verb *simplify*:

> Our mission is to simplify the process of posting or searching [NOUN].

Another is to use the verb *streamline*:

> Our mission is to streamline the process of posting or searching [NOUN].

A less politic choice might be the verb *idiot-proof*:

> Our mission is to idiot-proof the process of posting or searching [NOUN].

And of course (as Josh61 points out in his answer) you could always swap in the verb *facilitate*.

Answer (score 0):

Our aim is to **ease** posting and searching.

Or,

Our aim is to make posting and searching **congenial** and **convenient**.